# Shortcuts or autofill for contact info in UITextFields

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios10

When I'm in Safari in iOS, and I hit a form that requires I enter name and address, I get shortcuts in the keyboard area. For example, here is the keyboard when the focus is in a first name field. I can tap "Robert" instead of typing a name.

[image]

A similar thing happens for fields for last name, phone, email, zip code.

Can I get a similar thing in a native iOS app, in a `UITextField`? Is there a way to mark a field so that the keyboard will offer these shortcut suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can turn on or off it by set `autocorrectionType` of `UITextField`. Default value of `autocorrectionType` is `UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault` . It means you don't need to do anything, by default it will be showed.

> UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes; // Turn on
>
> UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault; // Turn on
>
> UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // Turn off

But beside of set `autocorrectionType` value, you need to make sure `Predictive` in `Keyboards Setting` of device is turned on. If `Predictive` is turned off, suggestion won't be displayed even you changed `autocorrectionType` to `UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes`.

**UPDATE**

You can change `textContentType` to choose with type of suggestion will be shown. Suggestions are from the `Contacts`. For example, you want phone suggestion

```
textField.textContentType = UITextContentTypeTelephoneNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you. We want their phone number to be suggested first / front-and-center.  How does one identify the field as a phone number field? or email field?

Comment: @finneycanhelp I have updated answer. You can take a look ;)

Comment: Works great, @trungduc . Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, but note that some of this is new in iOS 11 and does not work in iOS 10.

Comment: @RobN `textContentType` is available in iOS 10. You can check here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1649656-textcontenttype?language=objc

Comment: Yes, that property is the there, but the behavior I wanted -- offering the user a way to quickly fill in their name, phone, or email with a single tap -- that behavior is new in iOS 11.

Comment: Oh! So, even though the following values are available as of iOS 10, they were not used in iOS 10?: UITextContentTypeEmailAddress, UITextContentTypeTelephoneNumber, UITextContentTypeGivenName, UITextContentTypeFamilyName (objective-c version shared). Weird, but anything is possible.

Comment: @finneycanhelp confirm that it works totally fine on iOS 10 except *UITextContentTypeEmailAddress, UITextContentTypeTelephoneNumber, UITextContentTypeGivenName, UITextContentTypeFamilyName*. Actually, i don't know why they don't work.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @trungduc for that information and for a great question that I was able to easily add a bounty of 50 reputation points to. I applaud you. :)

Comment: @finneycanhelp so sorry for my bad English. I mean everything works including your types. Not except. My mistake. And again, i tried and eveything works on iOS 10 ;)

Comment: Ah! I understand. No apology needed @trungduc Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented everything in the answer here but the suggestions still aren't showing for me on iOS 13. Anyone have any ideas? I found an apple thread where some users reported bugginess as of late: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120703

Comment: After testing with multiple devices across various OS versions, it appears as though Apple has somehow restricted this autofill functionality on iOS 13. It still works on iOS 12, so they must have rolled this functionality back.

Answer (score 2):

One note, if you have email and password on a screen, sometimes the native keychain detection overrides textContentType=email so autofill using textContentType stops working for the email field. For things like "create account" where they don't likely have existing credentials in keychain it's best to disable the keychain. To fix this

To disable keychain, just do this: `passwordTextField.textContentType = @"";`

Then email autofill should work again:
`emailTextField.textContentType = UITextContentTypeEmail;`

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 13, I've found that email suggestions are only enabled if you set **all 3** of the following properties:

```
emailTextField.textContentType = .emailAddress
emailTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
emailTextField.autocorrectionType = .yes
```

You can do it programatically or via storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

My Observation in iOS 13.2 is, I disabled Auto-fill option from keychain settings.
And then it started suggesting the email
with

```
emailTextField.textContentType = .emailAddress
```

[image]